# nVidia GeForce 2 Aopen MX-400 64 Mb video card is slow

Tags: video, performance

My motherboard burned out and I replaced it with another lga755 with a better processor, E8400 4 core vs E5200 2 core,  with more memory,  6 Gb.

The motherboard did not come with integrated graphics so I had to get a video card. The video card is an nVidia GeForce 2 Aopen MX-400 64 Mb.

Video performance is very slow at about 1 frame per second. This makes it impossible to view YouTube. Before with the slower processor and 2 Gb RAM it was fine. The hardware info printout says it is using the nouveau driver.

*Is there a better video card to try?*

Comment: Have you tried actually installing the NVidia drivers? The `nouveau` drivers tend to leave a lot to be desired.

Comment: Hardware recommendations are off topic here. GeForce 2 seems awfully outdated and underpowered though. It was first released in 2000. I doubt you'll find drivers to enable hardware acceleration on current operating systems for it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you look at the [performance index of your card](http://www.videocardbenchmark.net/gpu.php?gpu=GeForce2+MX%2FMX+400&id=1479), it's absolutely normal that you get this kind of speed…  Nothing Ubuntu can do about this!

Note to low-quality reviewers: That's it!

Comment: As you're a reputation 6 user: If this answer helped you, don't forget to click the grey **☑** at the left of this text, which means [Yes, this answer is valid](http://askubuntu.com/help/accepted-answer)!  **;-)**

Answer (score 0):

EVGA GeForce 8400 GS. This graphics card is around the same price range as the one you have but it has 1 GB of vram which should be more than enough to watch videos on the internet.

Comment: I did not try the nvidia drivers. Some of the posts said that the support has not been carried forward to the later Ubuntu releases.

Comment: Thanks Michael. Does the nouveau driver work well with this model?